# React DangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

How Can I render Component children as Html with react dangerouslySetInnerHtml, if
I set text it works fine, but if I set Html this return [object Object]

```
    class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.children}}>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

1) ReactDOM.render(
  <App> Test </App>,
 document.getElementById('root')); --- Works


2) ReactDOM.render(
  <App> <p>Test</p> </App>,
 document.getElementById('root')); --- return [object Object]
```

[Link to JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/titupisufi/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This doesn't work because the value of `__html` needs to be a string, but you are passing an Object, more specifically a React Component...

Comment: ... but why are you using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` for? I don't see what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: this is just an example I need use dangerouslySetInnerHtml in my project, any other idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in the comments, you are getting `[object Object]` in the output because `__html` needs to be a string, but you are passing the React Component created from `<p>Test</p>`.

It is still unclear for me why you want to do this, but to do what you are asking for you need to pass a string.

So you can do one of the following:

```
<App>{"<p>Test</p>"}</App>
```

or

```
<App children="<p>Test</p>" />
```

both are equivalent and pass your markup as a string, which will then become the value for `__html`.

---

**Note!**

This will only work for normal HTML - not React Components written in JSX!

For example, this will **not** work:

```
<App children="<Foo>Test</Foo>" />
```